# Apache 2.4 Loads Image Files Even Without Extension. Why?

Tags: url, apache, images, file-extension

I have an HTML page with the following:

```
<img src=J3 width="100" height="150" alt="Student Name" style="float:left;"/>
```

In the same directory there is an image file, `J3.jpg`.  The page containing the above image element successfully loads the image file, and I cannot figure out why.  (I know the `src=` attribute is mangled; I am a college teacher and this is student work.)

Each student's work in in /home/userid/public_html.  Here is the relevant section of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:

```
<Directory /home/*/public_html>
    AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
    <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Limit>
    <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```

A search for MultiViews in httpd.conf finds only two comment lines, so MultiViews aren't enabled anyplace else.  There is no `mod_rewrite` in the configuration file.

There is an .htaccess file in each student's directory.  No MultiViews there, either, but for completeness, here is the one in question:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
Satisfy any
Deny from all
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/users
AuthGroupFile /etc/httpd/groups
Require user [redacted]
Require group professors
```

My goal is to change *httpd.conf* so that the above no longer works and then tell students to do it right.

There *was* a MultiViews in the above directory section.  I removed it and restarted `httpd` before posting here.  I have checked /var/log/messages to be absolutely, positively sure that the HTTP daemon was restarted successfully.

If I copy the contents of the student's public_html directory to a directory under the server root, specifically `/var/www/html/2015_02/student/` the picture does *not* display, so it is something about either that student's directory or the way all the student directories are set up in the configuration above.  The test below rules out a problem with that particular directory.

I built a fake student directory, `/home/bbrown/public_html/` and placed a jpeg in it.  I *can* display it without the `.jpg` extension, *e.g.* `http://weblab.spsu.edu/~bbrown/bbrown_quad_175` and the URL remains unchanged, without the extension.  Something is wrong with the configuration, possibly in the `<Directory /home/*/public_html>` section above.  This was all after removing `MultiViews` and restarting, so there is no possibility the image was cached and served from cache.

Comment: Does the student know why this works?

Comment: @w3d: No, he doesn't.

Comment: This might be a redirection also; if visiting J3 directly shows a final URL of http://example.com/path/J3 that suggests MultiViews, while showing a final URL of http://example.com/path/J3.jpg indicates a redirect or use of mod_rewrite. I'd investigate this using `curl --head http://example.com/path/J3`

Comment: @ChrisBurgess A final URL of `J3` could also be an _internal rewrite_ using mod_rewrite.

Comment: @ChrisBurgess:  I am utterly baffled.  If I visit `http://weblab.spsu.edu/~student/J3` (with the real student name) the picture is displayed with the URL unchanged, *i.e.* `http://weblab.spsu.edu/~student/J3`.  This is a very new installation of Apache on Centos 7 and I'm the only one who's had his fingers in `httpd.conf` and I've done nothing with mod_rewrite.  I'll go look and report back if I find anything in the default config, but I'm pretty sure not.

Comment: Have you tried a different file? Perhaps even a .png? A different student account?! Different browsers (just in case it's not a server issue)??!

Comment: I've edited the question to address different files.  I get the same results with Firefox, Chrome, and IE.

Comment: "A search for MultiViews in httpd.conf" - does httpd.conf `Include` any additional config files?

Comment: @w3d:  Aha!  Please make that an answer so that I can accept it!  There is a `userdir.conf` in `conf.d` that's implicitly included.

Comment: Glad you found it! And what was in `userdir.conf`? If it's `Options +MultiViews` then Stephen's answer is really the correct one.

Comment: Yes, there was an `Options Multiviews` there, too.  I've accepted Stephen's answer, but the real problem was that I had forgotten that the contents of `conf.d` are included implicitly.  *Thank you!*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This feature of Apache is known as "MultiViews" and it is handled by the [content negotiation module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html):

> ...if `/some/dir` has MultiViews enabled, and `/some/dir/foo` does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for files named `foo.*`, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's requirements.

It can be disabled with the configuration `Options -MultiViews` as described in this question from ServerFault: [apache multiviews, how to disable it](https://serverfault.com/questions/264954/apache-multiviews-how-to-disable-it).

The MultiViews option can appear in the main `httpd.conf` file, in a `.htaccess` file, or in files included with an `Include` directive, such as those in `/etc/httpd/conf.d`.  Just checking the main configuration file is not enough.

Comment: Note that `MultiViews` must be explicitly enabled by name, it's not part of the `All` option - so is never enabled by default. So, if you are in control of the server it might be preferable to _remove_ the directive that enables it in order to "disable" it.

Comment: I thought MultiViews was the problem, but removed if from the config, and the picture still displays. (After restarting HTTPD.)

Comment: @BobBrown Have you cleared the browser cache? And `MultiViews` is not enabled in .htaccess?

Comment: @w3d:  Check.  Cache cleared.  No Multiviews in .htaccess.

Comment: @BobBrown Just to be sure, have you explicitly tried `Options -MultiViews` in .htaccess, to disable it - just in case it is being enabled _somewhere_!?

Comment: @w3d:  I had not tried that.  I just did after reading your comment and got a 500 error.  I've edited my question to include what I hope is the relevant portion of `httpd.conf` and also the .htaccess.  I put `Options -Multiviews` just before `AuthType Basic`.  I'll go read the docs to see what I did wrong.

Comment: @BobBrown: The 500 error is probably because the `AllowOverride` directive in httpd.conf is blocking `MultiViews` in .htaccess (so it can't be enabled either).